# Access home security system through other network?

Tags: networking, surveillance-cameras

I'm looking to connect my phone to my building security cameras and gates.
I've been using the same app I use on my wall-mounted tablet and managed to set all the settings correctly.

The only problem i've just came to is trying to connect from outside the network.
I am currently opening an hotspot from my wall-mounted tablet, connected to the building's internet router, and it's connected to the other devices (cameras, gates) by local ips.

I have the public ip address, which is

> 62.2XX.XX.XXX

but when trying to connect from an other network - i'm being forwarded automaticly to the DVR system, which local IP address is

> 192.168.14.100.

In order to open the gate for example, I need to send the request from the app to

> 192.168.14.99

for example - but still, it's a LOCAL ip address.

My general question is, how do I access that

> 192.168.14.99

local ip from outside the network?

Hope the explanation was good enough. Thanks :)

Comment: ask the building manager

Comment: if you are opening a hotspot that is bridged to the building security system, then you are creating a security breach that may cost you a lot of money if someone breaks into the system and you get sued for damages as a result

Comment: @jsotola he doesn't have knowledge in these things. And yes, i'm aware of it - it was done only to get it working. The hotspot is also password protected of course and it's not a reasonable solution because I must be in my home to be able to use it.
Is there a way to do it with the data I've provided?

Comment: Asked and answered yesterday on SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions/1462449/i-have-a-domain-static-ip-and-many-devices-id-like-to-access-outside-my-house